# Optimized code for only max value in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

hi there I designed a blog page....per page 10 artilcs!

I want return biggest time (stamptime) for each 10 articls (like publish up time,publish down time,created,modifed time) to create meta tag.

so I have a list of 10 artiles (each article is an array with all parameters like date,content,title,...) that I saved them in $list array.

like this:

```
$list =  array ( array('id' => '1', 'modifed ' => '123123123' ...
```

I want return biggest value...the articls are mixed.

I use this code:

```
   $data['created'] = array_reduce($list, function ($a, $b) {
        return @$a['created'] > $b['created'] ? $a : $b ;

    $data['modified'] = array_reduce($list, function ($a, $b) {
        return @$a['modified'] > $b['modified'] ? $a : $b ;

    $data['publish_up'] = array_reduce($list, function ($a, $b) {
        return @$a['publish_up'] > $b['publish_up'] ? $a : $b ;

    $data['publish_down'] = array_reduce($list, function ($a, $b) {
        return @$a['publish_down'] > $b['publish_down'] ? $a : $b ;
```

My only worry is it maybe has a bad effect in my loading page.

do you think this code is Optimized?

Comment: Your code is not complete. It lacks a proper, complete example of data you want to process, also the complete code you are using to process the data, as well as the final result you want to achieve. Explaining the preferences of sorting would also be nice, because they are not self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. But as Sven said, you need to be more specific.

```
//fake data
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'upd' => 111, 'created' => 333),
    array('id' => 2, 'upd' => 1203, 'created' => 43),
    array('id' => 3, 'upd' => 144, 'created' => 533),
);

// here, I'm first computing the max of each column
// I place the results in an array and returns ultimately the max
echo max(
    array(
        max(array_column($data, 'upd')),
        max(array_column($data, 'created'))
    )
);
// here, it returns 1203, as there is an element "upd" with value 1203
```

If you do not have php 5.5, you have the following options:

1. use a php implementation that matches the behaviour of php 5.5 : https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php
2. upgrade to php 5.5 ;)
3. implements the function with map

The option 3 leads to the following code:

```
echo max(
    array(
        max(array_map(function($arr){return $arr['upd'];}, $data)),
        max(array_map(function($arr){return $arr['created'];}, $data)),
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks. That's my answer but is it a php 5.5 function and I used an older in my server.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me knw if it is working now !